# Can't get jQuery's ajaxSuccess() to work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm writing a very simple todo app in Rails.

View:

```
h2 Your todos
ul#todo_list
  = render @todos
hr
  h4 Add new
  = form_for(Todo.new, url: {action: 'create'}, remote: true) do |form|
    = form.text_field :text
    = form.submit 'Add'
```

CoffeeScript:

```
class Todo
  constructor: () ->
    @bindEvents()

  bindEvents: () =>
    console.log 'test1'
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(@onAjaxSuccess)

  onAjaxSuccess: (event, xhr, settings) ->
    console.log 'test2'
    $('#todo_list').append(xhr)

  @isPresent: (element_id) ->
    $("##{element_id}").length > 0

$(()->
  new Todo if Todo.isPresent('todos')
)
```

When I create a new todo, `test1` is printed in the console. I get a proper 200 response. The `@onAjaxSuccess()` method is not fired (`test2` is not printed). Why?

UPDATE:

I've just read that `jquery-ujs` fires `ajax:success` event so I have also tried:

```
bindEvents: () =>
  console.log 'test1'
  $('#new_todo').on('ajax:success', @onAjaxSuccess)
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 The expected result is to print 'test2' in the console.

Comment: Is an ajax request called at `js` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yest, an ajax request is made because the form has `data-remote=true` attribute, and rails' `jquery-ujs` is using ajax here.

Comment: Have you checked network tab to confirm if request is made ? Or if response is an error message ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, I have. As I said - requests work, but catching the event doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that not `'ajax:success'` was fired but `'ajax:error.'` In the xhr I was returning html element and jQuery tried to parse it as JSON (tip: bind to `'ajax:complete'` and see what errors you get).

Solution - change data type of the form:

```
= form_for(Todo.new, url: {action: 'create'}, remote: true, html: { data: {type: :html} }) do |form|
    = form.text_field :text
    = form.submit 'Add'
```

Answer (score 1):

The

```
@onAjaxSuccess: (event, xhr, settings) ->
```

should be

```
onAjaxSuccess: (event, xhr, settings) ->
```

so that it gets added to the `prototype` and is accessible with `this`

Answer (score 0):

Note, have not tried `coffeescript` .

Is an ajax request is made at `javascript` at Question ?

The second parameter of [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) is [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. `append()` appears not to throw an error when an object is passed as parameter, but will not append object as string to element.

```
var obj = {"abc":"123"};
$("body").append(obj);
```

If an ajax request is made by `form` submitting at `form.submit` ?, you should be able to use `$("#todo_list").append(xhr.responseText)` to append response of ajax request to element.

Comment: An ajax request is made - this is done by Rails. I get a response that I want.

I don't even get into `onAjaxSuccess` method, so the problem doesn't concern `append`.

Comment: Does it matter that `@onAjaxSuccess` is defined after `$(document).ajaxSuccess(@onAjaxSuccess)` , `bindEvents`  ? Have you tried placing `bindEvents` after `@onAjaxSuccess: (event, xhr, settings) ->` ? Or are they separate functions ? Is `form` submitted before `$(document).ajaxSuccess(@onAjaxSuccess)` event handler is defined ?